# Left Join no Sql Server

Tags: sql, comandos

Tenho uma dúvida, existe alguma diferença em executar as querys abaixo?

```
SELECT C.NOMECARGO, F.NOMEFUNCIONARIO
FROM CARGO AS C
LEFT JOIN FUNCIONARIO AS F 
ON C.IDCARGO = F.IDCARGO
```

```sql
SELECT C.NOMECARGO, F.NOMEFUNCIONARIO
FROM CARGO AS C
LEFT JOIN FUNCIONARIO AS F 
ON F.IDCARGO = C.IDCARGO
```

Comment: Ola, Ambas trazem todos os cargos que possuem ou não funcionario, a ordem das chaves não importa neste caso

Comment: Então, independente da ordem das chaves a minha consulta sempre será a mesma ?

Comment: isso, o resultado é o mesmo

Comment: André, Muito obrigado!!!

Comment: Como o @André disse, o resultado será o mesmo, porém é uma boa prática adotar um padrão. Aqui, no trabalho, uso como padrão a segunda opção que você mencionou (primeiro a tabela que estou fazendo o Join e depois a tabela com que estou relacionando.

Comment: Entendi, muito obrigado pessoal !!!